# Multiple jQuery UI Tabs on Page: Close all other tabs when another is opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I've got several rows of of separate jQuery Tabs. How do I get the separated tabs to close when another is opened (so at max, 1 is open at any given time on the page):

Markup:

```
<!-- First Leadership Row -->
<div id="leadershipTabs1" class="leadershipTabs leadershipContentContainer contentContainer clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#leader1-slug">Leader 1 Tab Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#leader2-slug">Leader 2 Tab Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#leader3-slug">Leader 3 Tab Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#leader4-slug">Leader 4 Tab Link</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="leader1-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 1 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leader2-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 2 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leader3-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 3 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leader4-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 4 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

</div><!-- #leadershipTabs -->
<!-- #First Leadership Row -->

<!-- Second Leadership Row -->
<div id="leadershipTabs2" class="leadershipTabs leadershipContentContainer contentContainer clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#leader5-slug">Leader 5 Tab Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#leader6-slug">Leader 6 Tab Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#leader7-slug">Leader 7 Tab Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#leader8-slug">Leader 8 Tab Link</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="leader5-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 5 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leader6-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 6 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leader7-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 7 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leader8-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent"><!-- Leader 8 Content Here --></div>
    </div>

</div><!-- #leadershipTabs -->
<!-- #Second Leadership Row -->
```

Firing the jQuery Tabs:

```
jQuery('.leadershipTabs').tabs({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I could find was that you were not including links inside the

tags. These links must have an href that matches the id of the divs you made below. Eg:

```js
jQuery('.leadershipTabs').tabs({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
});

$('li').click(function () {
    var dom = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $('.leaderPod').not(dom).hide();
    $('.ui-tabs-active').not(this).removeClass('ui-tabs-active');
    $('.ui-state-active').not(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');
    document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')).scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="leadershipTabs1" class="leadershipTabs leadershipContentContainer contentContainer clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li id="anchor1"><a href="#leader1-slug">Leader 1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="anchor2"><a href="#leader2-slug">Leader 2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="anchor3"><a href="#leader3-slug">Leader 3</a>
        </li>
        <li id="anchor4"><a href="#leader4-slug">Leader 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="leader1-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leader2-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leader3-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leader4-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- #leadershipTabs -->
<!-- #First Leadership Row -->
<!-- Second Leadership Row -->
<div id="leadershipTabs2" class="leadershipTabs leadershipContentContainer contentContainer clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li id="anchor5"><a href="#leader5-slug">Leader 5</a>
        </li>
        <li id="anchor6"><a href="#leader6-slug">Leader 6</a>
        </li>
        <li id="anchor7"><a href="#leader7-slug">Leader 7</a>
        </li>
        <li id="anchor8"><a href="#leader8-slug">Leader 8</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="leader5-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leader6-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leader7-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="leader8-slug" class="leaderPod">
        <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- #leadershipTabs -->
<!-- #Second Leadership Row -->
```

Comment: I over simplified my code. I did have the anchor tags in my unordered lists. I've updated my question content to relfect. The tabs work as expected now. I just can have Leader 1 and Leader 5 open simultaneously. I want when Leader 5's link is clicked, Leader 1 closes.

Comment: I added a snippet of jquery that will do exactly that. when any 'li' is clicked all items of class leaderPod are hidden except for the one clicked. :)

Comment: I get what this is doing, but my URLs aren't being updated with a hash equal to those in the ul.

Comment: I don't believe I understand. Could you explain in further detail?

Comment: When clicking on any of the links in the URLs, no hash is added to the page's URL. It just switches tab (no hash change)

Comment: now that i added 'window.location.hash = dom;' to the jquery, does it work now? i can't test it because it can't work in jsfiddle...

Comment: No, because no hash is ever visible on the page. Whether a tab is open or not, the URL remains domain.com/about/leadership/ At no point does it add anything like domain.com/about/leadership/#leader1-slug

Comment: I'm not sure then. You should add this requirement to your question. jQuery's designed links are not meant to add hashes to the top, they are keywords that link in the material below.

Comment: It not a requirement for me. The solution you've offered doesn't work as it's looking for window.location.hash which never shows up, so it never gets fired, unless I'm misunderstanding your solution's code.

Comment: Still trying to solve this tonight, tried your li click function again and it works. Apologize, but it was not working before tonight. Now I just need to get it to scroll to the on click.

Comment: Try adding anchor tags to each <li> tag. I have now included this in my example, with one more line of javascript as well (at the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to oMiKeY for pointing me in the right direction.  However, when I run the above sample, it is not completely functional.  For example: click Leader 1, then click Leader 5, and then click Leader 1 again.  Unfortunately, Leader 1 eats the click and does not display its content because it doesn't know that its content was hidden using css, jquery thinks it is still there.

First I slightly changed the class naming structure so the related elements: tabs group `<div id>`, `<li>` anchor, and the panels `<div id>` all begin with either leader1 or leader2.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="leader1Tabs" class="leadershipTabs leadershipContentContainer contentContainer clearfix">
<ul>
    <li id="anchor1"><a href="#leader1-1">Leader 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="anchor2"><a href="#leader1-2">Leader 2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="anchor3"><a href="#leader1-3">Leader 3</a>
    </li>
    <li id="anchor4"><a href="#leader1-4">Leader 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="leader1-1" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="leader1-2" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="leader1-3" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="leader1-4" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="leader2Tabs" class="leadershipTabs leadershipContentContainer contentContainer clearfix">
<ul>
    <li id="anchor5"><a href="#leader2-5">Leader 5</a>
    </li>
    <li id="anchor6"><a href="#leader2-6">Leader 6</a>
    </li>
    <li id="anchor7"><a href="#leader2-7">Leader 7</a>
    </li>
    <li id="anchor8"><a href="#leader2-8">Leader 8</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="leader2-5" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="leader2-6" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="leader2-7" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="leader2-8" class="leaderPod">
    <div class="leaderPodContent ctrContent">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then use the built-in jquery-ui tabs function to close the previous tab:

```
    var hold; //the previous active tab
    var dom; //the current active tab
    $('li').click(function () {
        dom = $(this).find('a').attr('href');  //example results are #leader1-1 or #leader2-5
        dom = dom.substring(1,8);  //use substring to return only 'leader1' or 'leader2'
        if ((hold == undefined)){  //for the first tab click
            hold = dom;  //to set the previous active tab
        }else if(dom !== hold){  //on all subsequent clicks, close the previous active tab
            $('#'+hold).tabs({active:false});  //jquery-ui tabs function
            hold = dom;  //update the previous tab
        }
    });
```

While the user clicks within a single tabs group, the test variables will both come back the same, both leader1 or both leader2.  When the user clicks another tabs group, the test variables don't match and the previous tabs group is closed.